# Login to a jsp website using Requests

Tags: python, jsp, python-requests

I have the following script:

```
import requests 
payload = {'j_username': 'user', 'password': 'pass'}
with requests.Session() as s:
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36'}
    p = s.post('https://idp.mls.ntreis.net/idp/Authn/UserPassword', data=payload,headers=headers) 
    r = s.get('https://ssoportal.mls.ntreis.net/') 
    print(r.text)
```

But the print `r.text` is showing me the html source of `https://idp.mls.ntreis.net/idp/Authn/UserPassword` without being logged in

Thanks for the help!

Comment: May I see `p.status_code`.

Comment: i've got 200.. that's mean Ok right ?

Comment: Yes, OK. But it seems you aren't authenticated for the Subdomain `'https://ssoportal.mls.ntreis.net/' or you have to use a **Token** or a **Cookie**. Check all Response Headers you got. Relevant: [requests login with redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021735/7414759)

Comment: I still have the same prob

Comment: It seems you are going to simulate a `form` Login. Looking at the URL Form there are 4 Fields, you are using only 2.