# How can I log in this specific website using Python Requests?

Tags: python, forms, authentication, python-requests

I am trying to log in this website using the following request but it doesn't work

> The cookie never contains 'userid'.

What should I change? Do I need to add headers in my post request?

```
import requests

payload = {
    'ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$Username': 'myemail@email.com',
    'ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$Password': 'mypassword',
    'ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$cbxRememberMe' : 'on',
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    login_page = s.get('http://www.bentekenergy.com/')
    response = s.post('http://benport.bentekenergy.com/Login.aspx', data=payload)
    if 'userid' in response.cookies:
       print("connected")
    else:
       print("not connected")
```

Edit 1 (following comments):
I am not sure about what to put in the request headers, below is what I tried, but unsuccessfully.

```
request_headers = {
    'Accept':'image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Cookie':'ACOOKIE=C8ctADJmMTc1YTRhLTBiMTEtNGViOC1iZjE0LTM5NTNkZDVmMDc1YwAAAAABAAAASGYBALlflFnvWZRZAQAAAABLAAC5X5RZ71mUWQAAAAA-',
    'Host':'statse.webtrendslive.com',
    'Referer':'https://benport.bentekenergy.com/Login.aspx',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Edit 2 (following stovfl answer):

I use now the following payload, fill each attributes with the value in the form and complete it with username, password and rememberMe.
I also tried with the following headers in the request.
Still not connected

```
payload = {
    '__VIEWSTATE' : '',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' : '',
    '__PREVIOUSPAGE' : '',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION' : '',
    'isAuthenticated' : 'False',
    'ctl00$hfAccessKey' : '',
    'ctl00$hfVisibility' : '',
    'ctl00$hfDateTime' : '',
    'ctl00$hfHash' : '',
    'ctl00$hfAnnouncementsUrl' : '',
    'ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$Username' : '',
    'ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$Password' : '',
    'ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$cbxRememberMe' : '',
}

request_headers = {
        'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
        'Connection':'keep-alive',
        'Content-Length':'7522',
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Cookie':'',
        'Host':'benport.bentekenergy.com',
        'Origin':'https://benport.bentekenergy.com',
        'Referer':'https://benport.bentekenergy.com/Login.aspx',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
response = s.get('http://benport.bentekenergy.com/Login.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
if soup.find("input", {"name" : "ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$Username"}):
    print("not connected")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
    for element in soup.select("input"): 
       if element.get("name") in payload:
           payload[element.get("name")] = element.get("value")

    payload['ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$Username'] = 'myemail@email.com'
    payload['ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$Password'] = 'mypassword'
    payload['ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$cbxRememberMe'] = 'on'

    response = s.post('http://benport.bentekenergy.com/Login.aspx', data=payload, headers=request_headers)

    print (s.cookies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    if soup.find("input", {"name" : "ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$Username"}):
            print("not connected")
    else:
            print("connected")
```

s.cookies contains:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie BenportState=q1k2r2eqftltjm55igy5mg55 for .bentekenergy.com/>, <Cookie RememberMe=True for .bentekenergy.com/>]>
```

Edit 3 (answer!):

I added

```
'__EVENTTARGET' : ''
```

in the payload and filled it with the value 'ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$btnSignIn'

Now I am connected!
NB: the headers were not necessary, just the payload

Comment: Yeah, try adding headers

Comment: I would suggest to use Selenium library for such tasks.

Comment: @AnkurSharma that's overkill for this case...

Comment: Paul - try changing your get url to be the same url as the post url - that way you make sure you're getting any relevant cookies the login page sends back before posting your data.

Comment: Inspect the network traffic, you need to post more parameters.

Comment: @JonClements I change the url but still not connected.

Comment: @t.m.adam could you give me more details on where i should look, I tried but it got me confused

Comment: In your browser > inspect element > network > params. Also check `s.cookies` not `response.cookies`

Comment: I looked at the requests sent using the inspector (that is where I found the headers). What parameters are you referring to?

Comment: Why do you expect `'userid' in response.cookies`, show Output of `print(response.cookies)` instead.

Comment: If you're using chrome it's inspect > network > headers > form data

Comment: It contains "<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie RememberMe=False for .bentekenergy.com/>]>".

Comment: @t.m.adam am I supposed to add the parameters at the bottom like "ctl00$hfAccessKey"? If yes, even the parameter "ctl00$hfHash" (which changes everytime)?

Comment: I think you should. You can get the names and values from `login_page.content` with `bs4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Comment**: ... found that there is a parameter '__EVENTTARGET' that was not in the payload. It needed to contain 'ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$btnSignIn'. Now I am connected!

Yes, overlooked the `Submit Button`, there is a `Javascript`:

```
href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$headerLoginCtrl$btnSignIn&quot;,
```

Relevant: [SO Answer How To see POST Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021735/7414759)

---

> **Comment**: ... based on your answer (Edit 2). Still not connected

1. You are using `http` instead of `https`
   Will be Auto-Redirected to `https`.
2. The `<RequestsCookieJar` has changed, so some progress.
   I'm still unsure about your Authenticated Check: `if soup.find("input", {"name"...`.
   Have you Check the Page Content?
   Any Error Message?
3. Don't use `BeautifulSoup(...` your following Requests should be using `Session s` to reuse the assigned `Cookie`.
   E.g. `response = s.get('<url to some resticted page>`
4. Try `request_headers` with **only** `'User-Agent'`

---

> **Analysis <form>**:
>   Login URL: https://benport.bentekenergy.com/Login.aspx
>   Form: action: `/Login.aspx`, method: `post`

If `value` **not** `empty` means: **Pre-Set-Values** from Login Page.

```
 1:input type:hidden   value:/wEPDwUKLT... id:__VIEWSTATE 
 2:input type:hidden   value:0BA31D5D      id:__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR 
 3:input type:hidden   value:2gILTn0H1S... id:__PREVIOUSPAGE 
 4:input type:hidden   value:/wEWDAKIr6... id:__EVENTVALIDATION 
 5:input type:hidden   value:False         id:isAuthenticated 
 6:input type:hidden   value:nu66O9eqvE    id:ctl00_hfAccessKey 
 7:input type:hidden   value:public        id:ctl00_hfVisibility 
 8:input type:hidden   value:08%2F16%2F... id:ctl00_hfDateTime 
 9:input type:hidden   value:3AB353573D... id:ctl00_hfHash 
10:input type:hidden   value://announce... id:ctl00_hfAnnouncementsUrl 
11:input type:text     value:empty         id:ctl00_MasterMainContent_LoginCtrl_Username 
12:input type:password value:empty         id:ctl00_MasterMainContent_LoginCtrl_Password 
13:input type:checkbox value:empty         id:ctl00_MasterMainContent_LoginCtrl_cbxRememberMe
```

Comment: I just edited my post reflecting the changes based on your answer (Edit 2). Still not connected

Comment: Tried your new suggestions with the headers and https: same results. I also checked the content of the pages, after the post request and s.get('<url to some resticted page>), I am redirected to the login page.
the cookies have changed and contain <Cookie BentekMarketingID=1167161 for .bentekenergy.com/>

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean about <form id="aspnetForm">

Comment: Got you. I guess it should be in the payload like this: 'aspnetForm' : 'a_value' ? (maybe the action value or onsubmit?

Comment: @Paul: Are you able to show the Browser `post` like in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021735/7414759)

Comment: Thanks to your comment I found that there is a parameter '__EVENTTARGET' that was not in the payload. It needed to contain 'ctl00$MasterMainContent$LoginCtrl$btnSignIn'. Now I am connected!